# Lotus Notes Interop.Domino.dll

Tags: .net, interop, com-interop, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Where can the Lotus Notes **(Interop.)Domino.dll** be downloaded ? Must I have installed a Lotus Client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [zip file](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lotusnoteintegrator/WindowsApplication2.zip) has it.

Answer (score 1):

In Domino R9,file domobj.tlb can also achieve the same job. I use it in C#.

Comment: This works for me with HCL Notes 11.0.1.  After installing the HCL Notes client, file can be added to your Visual Studio Project References by Browsing for `C:\HCL\Notes\domobj.tlb' when the HCL Notes client is installed in `C:\HCL\Notes'